# NSWindow closed its dealloc gets called still respondsToSelector Getting Called, and getting crashed on calling respondsToSelector:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, exception, document

I have developed Mac application, there is document is displayed from app delegate with addDocument , Now on close this nswindowcontroller's dealloc gets called, still repondsToSelector from other delegate methods like spilt view keeps hitting & as dealloc was called [super document] is null so respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance . is there. Please can anyone help to solve this? How to completely release this document?

Comment: Can you just show the code?

Comment: from appDeleagte  - 
       NSDocumentController *document = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
      [document addDocument:windowController];
Now when you close this windowController its dealloc is getting called. but still If I overwrite RespondsToSelector:
this window controller listens RespondsToSelector & after dealloc its document is null so it crashes.

How can it possible after dealloc this window listens RespondsToSelector??